# How to replace "|" from string in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub, stringr

I have data in the format

```
"TGXENG0002|Tenchi Muyo! GXP|2|Invasion|Non-Subscriber||Roku|US"
```

Now I want to count the occurrence `"|"` and then replace it with a blank

```
rokujune$pipecnt_1 <- gsub(pattern="|",replacement="",x = rokujune$Event_Label)
```

I have used this code and it does not work. Can anybody point me out the reason and possible solution?

And for counts of occurrence I am trying out the following code

```
rokujune$new<- str_count(rokujune$Event_Label,"|")
```

which also does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape the character.

```
gsub(pattern="\\|", replacement="", x=rokujune$Event_Label)
```

All regex languages have some set of special symbols that are interpreted as instructions rather than text characters. If you need to interpret such a symbol as a text character you have to escape the symbol in your regex pattern by adding the escape sequence.

Comment: Or just use `fixed = TRUE`

Comment: adding "\\" did solve my problem but, can you explain me what did you mean by escaping the character??

Comment: Please read `?regex` and especially the "metacharacter" part. regex uses some stored characters in order to run different operations, and you need to tell it that you don't want to run this specific operation, rather to find that actual character.

Comment: @pranav as David has already mentioned "|" is a special symbol, hence it requires escaping (adding "\\" before it) to be interpreted as a character.

Comment: Thank you David and Korvigo

Answer (score 0):

For counts of occurrence, try this:

```
nchar(gsub('[^|]','',rokujune$Event_Label))
[1] 7
```